# Run multiple servo on ROS with arduino

Tags: ros, rosseral-arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody,

i wanted to know is there any way out by which i can 2 or more servos at a time from a single subscriber. Currently i am running one servo on a single channel of arduino Due. But i require two servos to be run at a same time by giving them different angle values. like;

```
rostopic pub Servo1 std_msgs/Int16 230;
```

this passes 230 degree to the servo attached. But i want to control two at a time like;

```
rostopic pub Servo1 std_msgs/Int16 230 130 240;
```

230 for 1st servo; (degrees) 130 for 2nd servo; (degrees) 240 for 3rd servo...(degrees)

I would appreciate if someone puts a light on this issue.

thnks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/145951/run-multiple-servo-on-ros-with-arduino./) by [sonny](https://answers.ros.org/users/13381/sonny/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2014-03-29

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You've got two options. Most straightforward would be a basic custom message with an array. [This answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/9471/how-to-recieve-an-array-over-publisher-and-subscriber-python/) may help. Second option which is more elegant and involves less code is a [MultiArray](http://wiki.ros.org/std_msgs).

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2014-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [s1](https://answers.ros.org/users/21751/s1/) on 2015-09-22**:
can anyone give an example of MultiArray usage please.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

here is an example using MultiArray

```
#if (ARDUINO >= 100)
 #include <Arduino.h>
#else
 #include <WProgram.h>
#endif

#include <Servo.h> 
#include <ros.h>
#include "std_msgs/MultiArrayLayout.h"
#include "std_msgs/MultiArrayDimension.h"

#include "std_msgs/UInt16MultiArray.h"

ros::NodeHandle  nh;

Servo servo1;
Servo servo2;

void servo_cb( const std_msgs::UInt16MultiArray&  cmd_msg){
  servo1.write(cmd_msg.data[0]); //set servo angle, should be from 0-180  
  servo2.write(cmd_msg.data[1]); 
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH-digitalRead(13));  //toggle led  
}


ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::UInt16MultiArray> sub("servo", servo_cb);

void setup(){
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);

  nh.initNode();
  nh.subscribe(sub);

  
  servo1.attach(9); //attach it to pin 9
  servo2.attach(10);//attach it to pin10
}

void loop(){
  nh.spinOnce();
  delay(1);
}
```

Publisher:

```
 rostopic pub servo std_msgs/UInt16MultiArray '{data: [<angle1>, <angle2>]}'
```

---

Originally posted by [Chuong Nguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/23343/chuong-nguyen/) with karma: 136 on 2015-10-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [s1](https://answers.ros.org/users/21751/s1/) on 2015-10-16**:
thank you!!!

**Comment by [s1](https://answers.ros.org/users/21751/s1/) on 2015-12-23**:
is it possible to delay `servo2` so that I can time the action? In other words I dont want all of the servos to fire off at once.

**Comment by [Frank Lee](https://answers.ros.org/users/31663/frank-lee/) on 2017-09-05**:
Maybe consider publishing the message to servo 2 separately, delay accounted for?